# selenium action error after new chrome update : stale element reference element is not attached to the page document

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.PerformActions(IList`1 actionSequenceList)
at UITests.TestCases.User.Forms.AdvanceContols.DataGridPowerSelect() in C:\Expressbase.core\UITests\TestCases\User\Forms\AdvanceContols.cs:line 198

Answer (score 0):

My first guess from looking at the error message would be that the behavior of application you are testing changed. Usually this error means that a web element which was on the web page when you first grabbed it no longer exists when you try to use it again. You would need to find that element again.

However, if you do think it is the chrome drive, did you make sure to update the chrome driver your test is referencing to the chromedriver for 8.4?

Comment: My chrome drive version is : 84.0.4147.3001. and i have used wait.until clickable to see whether it is waiting, but still the error shows.

Comment: If the behavior change what is best way to recreate the object ?? @Fractal

Comment: the FindElement method. By Locator = By.Id("UserName");
 IWebElement UserName = driver.FindElement(Locator); https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/findelement-and-findelements-commands-in-c/